# Can i change the way the ir remote works?

Tags: ev3

I bought an EV3 and the first thing that I want to do with it is control models with the remote.

I finally discovered how to do this after a long search.

It can control [the Formula EV3 racing car](https://www.safaribooksonline.com/library/view/the-lego-mindstorms/9781457185366/ch12.html) with rack and pinion steering (where the angle of the 2 front wheels change instead of the 2 back wheels turning in the opposite direction to turn the car) When you use wheels it doesn't turn like when you use the other type of tires.

I'd like to use the remote that comes with the EV3 to do this, but I'm not sure how to modify the remote to support this type of control?

Comment: What EV3 model have you built, is it one of your own or one from the instructions provided with EV3?

Comment: The formulla race car

Answer (score 1):

If I understand your question correctly, you are asking how to use the following remote to control traditional car that has front wheel rack and pinion steering rather than a vehicle that skid steers using the rear wheels. Here's the remote:

[image: EV3 Remote]

This isn't ideal for controlling steering because both sets of buttons point forward. The easiest solution is to attach a wheel on the side of the remote that actuates one set of controls [like this](http://www.technicbricks.com/2008/02/tbs-techtips-010-extend-limits-of-your.html). Here's an example using the PF remote that could be adapted to work with the EV3 remote.

[image: remote with steering]

I don't know what your vehicle design looks like, but you may also want some sort of return to center steering system on the motor controlling the orientation of the front wheels if you haven't already built one. Here's one [simple example of this](http://www.eurobricks.com/forum/index.php?showtopic=54104):

[image: RTC steering]

Comment: Its the remote from the ev3

Comment: Ah. Of course it is. Sorry about that. I've updated my answer.